# Scala SQL - Read in file of ids and include id in WHERE clause in query

Tags: sql, scala, performance, io

I have a txt file of ids, one `BigInteger` id per line in a .txt file. I want to write a simple SQL query with Scala that reads these id's in and includes these ids in the where clause as I'm only interested in querying values for these particular ids only.

Sample .txt file

```
1234566789
9876543212
```

Sample query that assumes that $id is a set or list of ids in the .txt. file above.

```
spark.sql(f"""
  SELECT
    table_x.id,
    AVG(table_x.cost)
  FROM table_x
  WHERE table_x.id = $id
  GROUP BY table_x.id
  """)
```

I'm looking for something efficient. I think I can load in these ids and store them as a set in Scala and check if `table_x.id` exists in this set. But I'm not sure what the most efficient solution is for this as the .txt file of ids will be more than 100k in rows.

Comment: Is this an ongoing dynamic query or a one off?  If it's a one off you could create a temp table from the file and then query the IDs from the table.  Likewise you could paste them into VSCode or similar and turn them into a list of comma separated strings then use a `WHERE IN` filter

Comment: @iShaymus Is a temp table efficient? Also, I'm not sure how to parse it into a temp table from a .txt file.

Comment: It depends on how much data is in the .txt file, how many IDs?. What database and tools are you using.  I use Oracle databases and both SQL Developer and Toad have ways to create tables from Excel, CSV and Text files.  Your DB solution may likewise have similar functionality.  The `WHERE IN` option is likely your easiest choice if there's less than a thousand IDs.

Comment: About 100k ids are in the .txt.file

Comment: You will have to use a temp table as the limit on `WHERE IN` is 1000.  What DB are you using?

Comment: It's a RDS DB. Do you want to provide a solution?

Comment: Looks like you are using spark already? Just make a dataframe from the file and join with it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar enough with Amazon RDS to know what RDMS software could be used to get the text file to the database.  Perhaps it needs to be stored on Amazon S3?

I don't know which DB engine you are running on RDS but I'll give examples for Oracle since that's what I'm used to.

Once you have the file somewhere it can be accessed by the DB you would create a new table from the text file

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE MYSCHEMA.MY_ID_TABLE_NAME (
  MY_IDS varchar2(32), -- number if you're sure they will only ever be numeric
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

LOAD DATA
INFILE 'C:\path\to\my-super-ID-data.txt'
TRUNCATE
INTO TABLE MYSCHEMA.MY_ID_TABLE_NAME
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\r' --carriage return can be ',' for CSV
(
  MY_IDS
)
```

You should then have a single column table called `MYSCHEMA.MY_ID_TABLE_NAME` that contains all your IDs

At this point you would run your query as follows

```
spark.sql(f"""
  SELECT
    x.id,
    AVG(x.cost)
  FROM table_x x
  WHERE x.id IN (SELECT my_ids FROM MYSCHEMA.MY_ID_TABLE_NAME)
  GROUP BY x.id
  """)
```

Going forward if you wanted to rerun the query again with up to date IDs you would recreate the temp table from a new file, rinse and repeat.